# MS Graph API "Cannot convert a primitive value" during "user update process" using python

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I can create users in o365 and list them using python scripting.

I am now trying to run a very simple update and having an issue with applying a usage location (so I can also apply license which requires this) but when I do I get the following error:

> {'error': {'code': 'Request_BadRequest', 'message': "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'. See the inner exception for more details.", 'innerError': {'date': '2019-08-06T18:51:25', 'request-id': '4e6c89c2-e3c6-xxxxx'}}}

Obviously it's looking for some UID style entry but the field I am populating (according to api docs) is 2 character string. Am I making the request incorrectly?

Here is the code I am using for this specific task.

```
  # Update a user entry
  def updateUser(self,userupn,maildomain,usagelocation):
    userMail = userupn + '@' + maildomain
    header_params = {
      'Authorization': self.token_type + ' ' + self.access_token2,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    request_body = {
        #'accountEnabled': 'true',
        'usageLocation': usagelocation,
      }

    request_string = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/' + userMail
    response = requests.post(request_string, data=json.dumps(request_body), headers=header_params)
    data = response.json()
    return data
```

From what I can see in the api docs that should be enough to set the usageLocation to "US" or some other 2 letter value.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was a few issues and I was able to resolve them. Here is the working bit I ended up with for now. Incase anyone else comes behind me having similar issues.
The short version of the problem was I was using requests.post() instead of requests.patch().

```
  # Update a user entry
  def updateUser(self,userupn,maildomain,usagelocation):
    userMail = userupn + '@' + maildomain
    header_params = {
      'Authorization': self.token_type + ' ' + self.access_token2,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    request_body = {
        'accountEnabled': 'true',
        'passwordPolicies': 'DisablePasswordExpiration',
        'usageLocation': usagelocation,
        'country': usagelocation,
        'officeLocation': usagelocation,
      }

    request_string = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + userMail
    response = requests.patch(request_string, data=json.dumps(request_body), headers=header_params)
    return response
```